# how to loop though the exception cause chain in jspx

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jspx

I have a JSPX (X!) page where I want to show an exception (message and stacktrace) and all there cause exception. It is no problem to print the first exception, but I have not found a way to "interate" over all the cause exception.

of course I could do something like that:

```
<c:out value="${exception.message}" />
<c:out value="${exception.stacktrace}" />

<c:if test=${exception.cause not null}>
   <c:set var="cause1" "${exception.cause}" />
   <c:out value="${cause1.message}" />
   <c:out value="${cause1.stacktrace}" />

   <c:if test=${cause1.cause not null}>
      <c:set var="cause2" "${cause1.cause}" />
      <c:out value="${cause2.message}" />
      <c:out value="${cause2.stacktrace}" />

      <c:if test=${cause2.cause not null}>
         <c:set var="cause3" "${cause2.cause}" />
         <c:out value="${cause3.message}" />
         <c:out value="${cause3.stacktrace}" />
      </c:if>
   </c:if>
</c:if>
```

But this is ugly and will fail if there a more than 3 causes.

So my question is, how to build a `while` loop in jspx for such an scenario?

(*Please do not discuss that printing an exception is wrong at all.*)

Comment: What is `jspx`? May I know it? Never seen it before.

Comment: It related to jsp like HtmlX to Html. Or more precise is it well formed (in therms of xml) jsp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround could be to use a `foreach` running through the chain of causes.
The number of runs in the `foreach` would limit the number of exceptions that can be displayed.
Not very elegant but without neither a `while` nor a `break` it's probably the most "flexible" way...

```xml
<c:set var="current_exception" value="${exception}" />
<c:forEach begin="0" end="10" step="1" var="i">
  <c:if test="${not empty current_exception}">
    <c:out value="${current_exception.message}" />
    <c:out value="${current_exception.stacktrace}" />
    <c:set var="current_exception" value="${current_exception.cause}" />
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to express arbitrary `while` loop using JSTL tags, therefore you have to use scriptlets. Note that you can use scriptlets in JSPX as `<jsp:scriptlet>` elements.

Alternatively, you can prepare a desired representation of stacktrace in servlet (controller, etc). Perhaps it would be a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution might be to build a list of the exceptions first and then iterate over them using `c:forEach`.

Alternatively you could try to recursively include a jsp and pass the cause as a parameter. Something like this:

```
<!-- Exception.jspx -->     
<c:out value="${exception.message}" />
<c:out value="${exception.stacktrace}" />
<c:if test=${exception.cause not null}>
  <c:set var="exception" value="${exception.scope}"/>
  <c:import url="Exception.jspx/>      
</c:if>
```

Note that I didn't test this and it might not work as is (it's just a hint). We did something similar but used our own include and parameter tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<jsp:include>` recursively.

Here's how the sole body of `/WEB-INF/printexception.jsp` can look like:

```html
<c:out value="${exception.message}" />
<c:out value="${exception.stackTrace}" />
<c:if test="${not empty exception.cause}">
    <c:set var="exception" value="${exception.cause}" scope="request" />
    <jsp:include page="printexception.jsp" />
</c:if>
```

Reference it as follows in your main error page:

```html
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/printexception.jsp" />
```

Keep in mind that the stack level is usually "only" ~1000 deep, you hopefully don't get that deep nested exceptions :)

Answer (score 0):

Using JSTL 1.1+

```xml
${exception}
<div style="margin: 10px 0px 20px 60px">
   <c:forEach items="${exception.stackTrace}" var="entry">
      <c:out value="${entry}"/><br/>
   </c:forEach>
</div>
```

Comment: (Welcome to stack overflow), -- My problem is not the stacktrace but the cause of an exception (exception.cause), because the cause is not a list or array. Instead you have to call `e.getCause().getCause().getCause()...` .